# get_feature_names not found in countvectorizer()

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas, countvectorizer

I'm mining the Stack Overflow data dump of posts about deep learning libraries. I'd like to identify stop words in my corpus (like 'python' for instance). I want to get my feature names so I can identify the words with highest term frequencies.

I create my documents and my corpus as follows:

```
with open("StackOverflow_2018_Data.csv") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    pytorch_doc = ''
    tensorflow_doc = ''
    cotag_list = []
    keras_doc = ''
    counte = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if row[2] == 'tensorflow':
            tensorflow_doc += row[3] + ' '
        if row[2] == 'keras':
            keras_doc += row[3] + ' '
        if row[2] == 'pytorch':
            pytorch_doc += row[3] + ' '

corpus = [pytorch_doc, tensorflow_doc, keras_doc]
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
x = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(x)
x.toarray()
Dict = []
feat = x.get_feature_names()
for i,arr in enumerate(x):
    for x, ele in enumerate(arr):
        if i == 0:
            Dict += ('pytorch', feat[x], ele)
        if i == 1:
            Dict += ('tensorflow', feat[x], ele)
        if i == 2:
            Dict += ('keras', feat[x], ele)

sorted_arr = sorted(Dict, key=lambda tup: tup[2])
```

However, I am getting:

```
  File "sklearn_stopwords.py", line 83, in <module>
    main()
  File "sklearn_stopwords.py", line 50, in main
    feat = x.get_feature_names()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 686, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
AttributeError: get_feature_names not found
```

Comment: I think you need `vectorizer.get_feature_names()`.  The results of the fit_transform are a np.array.  The CountVectorizer object has the get_feature_names method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`get_feature_names` is a method in the CountVectorizer Object.  You are trying to access get_feature_names the results of fit_transform which is a scipy.sparse matrix.

You need to use `vectorizer.get_feature_names()`.

Try this MVCE:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
corpus = ['This is the first document.',
          'This is the second second document.',
          'And the third one.',
          'Is this the first document?']

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

features = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

features
```

Output:

```
['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third', 'this']
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar issue with my code. After reviewing the release notes for CountVectorizer, I learned that the **get_feature_names** method is no longer supported in **version 1.2** and above. However, it should work fine in **version 1.1 and earlier**. If you have upgraded your scikit-learn version to 1.2, I suggest using the **get_feature_names_out** method instead. You can find more details in the following link:

https://scikit-learn.org/1.1/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html?highlight=countvector

I hope this information is helpful. Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to use `get_feature_names_out` as the method `get_feature_names` was deprecated in the v1.0 branch but it wasn't fully removed until the v1.2 branch.