# Get feature names after sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I want to match the output np array with the features to make a new pandas dataframe

Here is my pipeline:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
# Categorical pipeline
categorical_preprocessing = Pipeline(
[
    ('Imputation', SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('Ordinal encoding', OrdinalEncoder(handle_unknown='use_encoded_value', unknown_value=-1)),
]
)
# Continuous pipeline
continuous_preprocessing = Pipeline(
[
     ('Imputation', SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')),
     ('Scaling', StandardScaler())
]
)
# Creating preprocessing pipeline
preprocessing = make_column_transformer(
     (continuous_preprocessing, continuous_cols),
     (categorical_preprocessing, categorical_cols),
)
# Final pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(
[('Preprocessing', preprocessing)]
)
```

Here is how I call it:

```
X_train = pipeline.fit_transform(X_train)
X_val = pipeline.transform(X_val)
X_test = pipeline.transform(X_test)
```

Here is what I get when trying to get the feature names:

```
pipeline['Preprocessing'].transformers_[1][1]['Ordinal encoding'].get_feature_names()
```

OUT:

```
AttributeError: 'OrdinalEncoder' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names'
```

Here is a SO question that was similar: [Sklearn Pipeline: Get feature names after OneHotEncode In ColumnTransformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54646709/sklearn-pipeline-get-feature-names-after-onehotencode-in-columntransformer)

Comment: What's your `sklearn` version?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55524004/6361531

Comment: @ScottBoston I am not using count vectorizer, I don't even have text data. I understand some sklearn methods have a get feature names but how can I be sure the columns from resulting dataset and the column names will match?

Comment: @richardec latest version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Point is that, as of today, some transformers do expose a method `.get_feature_names_out()` and some others do not, which generates some problems - for instance - whenever you want to create a *well-formatted* `DataFrame` from the np.array outputted by a `Pipeline` or `ColumnTransformer` instance. (Instead, afaik, `.get_feature_names()` was deprecated in latest versions in favor of `.get_feature_names_out()`).

For what concerns the transformers that you are using, [`StandardScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) belongs to the first category of transformers exposing the method, while both [`SimpleImputer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html) and [`OrdinalEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html) do belong to the second. The docs show the exposed methods within the *Methods* paragraphs. As said, this causes problems when doing something like `pd.DataFrame(pipeline.fit_transform(X_train), columns=pipeline.get_feature_names_out())` on your `pipeline`, but it would cause problems as well on your `categorical_preprocessing` and `continuous_preprocessing` pipelines (as in both cases at least one transformer lacks of the method) and on the `preprocessing` `ColumnTransformer` instance.

There's an ongoing attempt in `sklearn` to enrich *all* estimators with the `.get_feature_names_out()` method. It is tracked within [github issue #21308](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/21308), which, as you might see, branches in many PRs (each one dealing with a specific module). For instance, [issue #21079](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/21079) for the *preprocessing* module, which will enrich the `OrdinalEncoder` among the others, [issue #21078](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/21078) for the *impute* module, which will enrich the `SimpleImputer`. I guess that they'll be available in a new release as soon as  all the referenced PR will be merged.

In the meanwhile, imo, you should go with a custom solution that might fit your needs. Here's a simple example, which do not necessarily resemble your need, but which is meant to give a (possible) way of proceeding:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer, make_column_selector

X = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['London', 'London', 'Paris', 'Sallisaw', ''],
                  'title': ['His Last Bow', 'How Watson Learned the Trick', 'A Moveable Feast', 'The Grapes of Wrath', 'The Jungle'],
                  'expert_rating': [5, 3, 4, 5, np.NaN],
                  'user_rating': [4, 5, 4, np.NaN, 3]})
X
```

[image]

```
num_cols = X.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns.tolist()
cat_cols = X.select_dtypes(exclude=np.number).columns.tolist()

# Categorical pipeline
categorical_preprocessing = Pipeline(
[
    ('Imputation', SimpleImputer(missing_values='', strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('Ordinal encoding', OrdinalEncoder(handle_unknown='use_encoded_value', unknown_value=-1)),
]
)
# Continuous pipeline
continuous_preprocessing = Pipeline(
[
    ('Imputation', SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')),
    ('Scaling', StandardScaler())
]
)
# Creating preprocessing pipeline
preprocessing = make_column_transformer(
    (continuous_preprocessing, num_cols),
    (categorical_preprocessing, cat_cols),
)

# Final pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(
    [('Preprocessing', preprocessing)]
)

X_trans = pipeline.fit_transform(X)

pd.DataFrame(X_trans, columns= num_cols + cat_cols)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I did something similar where I just assigned the names of the columns to a newly created df